# How to prevent Groovy from creating fields from accessor methods?

Tags: groovy

If I have the following code:

```
class Person {
    String getName() {
        "John Doe"
    }

    boolean isMan() {
        true
    }
}

println new Person().properties
```

​
Then, it prints:

```
[class:class Person, man:true, name:John Doe]
```

How can I prevent groovy from creating the properties (man, name) based on the accessor methods? I understand why groovy creates the properties, but was hoping that there might be a way (like using some annotation) to prevent groovy from doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be aware that `new Person().properties` does not return a list of class properties in terms of class fields, but rather metaclass properties. Groovy uses a class called [`MetaBeanProperty`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/MetaBeanProperty.java) to represent both - class fields and accessor methods. If you compile your Groovy class you will get `.class` file that decompiles to something like this:

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class Person implements GroovyObject {
    public Person() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        MetaClass var2 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var2;
    }

    public String getName() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        return "John Doe";
    }

    public boolean isMan() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see there are no fileds created for your getter methods, however `new Person().properties` returns `name` and `man` properties because of `MetaBeanProperty`.

If you want to get a map of class fields only then you would have to filter the map returned by `new Person().properties`. `MetaBeanProperty` class has this method [`getField()`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/MetaBeanProperty.java#L153) that returns [`CachedField`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/CachedField.java) whenever given `MetaBeanProperty` is represented by a class field and `null` otherwise. Consider following example:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked

@CompileStatic
@TypeChecked
class Person {

    String email

    String getName() {
        "John Doe"
    }

    boolean isMan() {
        true
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def person = new Person()

        def fields = person.properties.findAll {
            (person.hasProperty(it.key.toString()) instanceof MetaBeanProperty) && ((MetaBeanProperty) person.hasProperty(it.key.toString())).getField() != null
        }

        println fields
    }
}
```

In this example we have added a field `email`. Filtering the list of properties according to the rule described above returns a following map:

```
[email:null]
```

And last but not least - this is what modified `Person` class looked like after decompiling `.class` file:

```
import Person._main_closure1;
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import groovy.lang.Reference;
import java.util.Map;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods;

public class Person implements GroovyObject {
    private String email;

    public Person() {
        MetaClass var1 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var1;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "John Doe";
    }

    public boolean isMan() {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Reference person = new Reference(new Person());
        Map fields = DefaultGroovyMethods.findAll(DefaultGroovyMethods.getProperties((Person)person.get()), new _main_closure1(Person.class, Person.class, person));
        DefaultGroovyMethods.println(Person.class, fields);
        Object var10000 = null;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String var1) {
        this.email = var1;
    }
}
```

Again, `getName()` and `isMan()` methods don't create class fields, `email` field with the default Groovy scope transformed to a private class field with accessor methods. Hope it helps.

#### Where class properties are created?

If you want to see and/or debug the place where `new Person().properties` map is created, take a look at [`MetaClassImpl.getProperties()` method in line 2083](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/MetaClassImpl.java#L2083). This is the method that your class calls to get the list of properties from metaclass. As you can see it accepts two types of properties - cached fields (a real class fields) and meta bean properties (properties that might be represented by a field or accessor method). There is no option to exclude getter methods from being retrieved from `getProperties()` method unfortunately.

If your intention is to exclude your accessor method from `new Person().properties` then the only way to achieve this is to rename the method so it is not seen as a accessor method (e.g. `getName()` -> `name()`). In this case Groovy's metaclass won't retrieve a meta bean property for such method and the value it returns won't be present in `new Person().properties` map.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I guess I am more interested in preventing groovy from creating the metaclass properties. How do I do that?

Comment: @Mi_Onim You can't achieve this. Creating method like `getName()` creates `MetaBeanProperty` that is returned with `new Person().properties`. If you rename `getName()` method to e.g. `name()` then Groovy metaclass won't see this method as a `MetaBeanProperty` and it won't be returned with `new Person().properties`.

Comment: @Mi_Onim I've updated the answer with explanation how `getProperties()` retrieves properties that it returns.